# Sony ICLA68 Preview Degrades in Quality after a second

Tags: troubleshooting, sony

I have had my Sony ICLA-68 for about a year now. I have always had problems with the images not coming out clear. I notice this when I am taking any kind of photo wither it be landscape, people, or light painting, the image I am seeing through the view finder or the LCD looks fine but after I take the photo the image becomes blurry and or soft. I notice it the most when I am taking macro shots. I use a tripod with a pluto trigger so I am not introducing any vibrations to the camera when the photo is being taken. Yet the images still come out bury.

For almost a year now I thought it was user error but recently I enabled the photo preview setting where it shows you the photo you took after you take it. I have noticed that the image I am seeing looks fantastic but then after about a second the image quality sharply degrades. [As you can see in this video I took](https://youtu.be/eyneBtWRwpU)

I noticed that when the image degrades the SD card light turns off. At first I figured it was because I was saving to a standard quality jpeg so I switched over to using Raw images instead but I still have this problem where the quality is lacking compared to what I saw through the view finder.

I thought this might have something to do with me using a class 6 SD card so I tried using a better SD card thinking that it could be because I was not using a class 10 SD card. After I made the switch to a class 10 SD card I saw no difference.

I looked at [this article](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43466/why-does-the-picture-on-my-cameras-rear-lcd-screen-look-fine-right-when-i-take)  and the accepted answer is because of vibrations being added to the photo when it has been taken which is not the case for me.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For me at least, your video is not very clear. Can you make another one? Longer, from further back, with a different thing being photographed maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the picture on my camera's rear LCD screen look fine right when I take the shutter, but then change?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43466/why-does-the-picture-on-my-cameras-rear-lcd-screen-look-fine-right-when-i-take)

Comment: The accepted answer of the linked question is about blurring due to movement in long exposure. This doesn't seem to apply for the video shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think the linked answers aren't really duplicates, I want to give another answer here.

What you see before and after the exposure is taken directly from the sensor.
At this time the camera does not really know yet, how the image will look in the end. 
The camera tries to apply all settings to the preview in EVF/LCD but this does not necessarily match the final result.
All effect on the image with respect to overall brightness, contrast, details, etc. are only an estimation done by the camera electronics.

After you took the image, the camera can read the real data from the sensor.
This time there is no need to estimate contrast etc. Now the values are fixed.

And now the created image can differ from the estimation you've seen before.

To improve speed the camera might prioritze writing into the file above showing the preview on the display. By doing this you are ready to fire again earlier.

On a side note: The same applies to lens correction if available.
Depending on your lens you can see the image be distorted after a while.

BTW: Did you enable or disable preview of "all effects" for the EVF? ;)

Comment: It comes enabled by default with no way to disable it unless you are in manual mode (which in this case I am not. I only use manual mode when I am shooting light painting stuff)

Comment: OK, that would've been too easy. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the viewfinder image and the quickly shown preview use the fast *nearest neighbor interpolation*, which looks eye-hurtingly sharp. Then after the second it shows you the real picture interpolated properly, and that doesn't look as sharp (although it has less noise and other problems).

See my answer in [Can you set the quality of image displayed when zoomed out in Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75732/can-you-set-the-quality-of-image-displayed-when-zoomed-out-in-lightroom/89293#89293)