# Mismatch between image quality on viewer and actual phtoto

Tags: focusing

I am using a Nikon D3200 and I think there is a mismatch between the image seen on the view-finder and the image which appears on the CCD array. I have never been able to achieve the sharp focus as one would expect. The image on the screen is sharp but the actual photos are poor. Any reason for this problem?

Comment: Is it the same as [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46969/why-do-i-see-focus-less-accurately-in-my-dslrs-viewfinder-and-screen-with-old-l)? I know that question talks about old lenses, but that may be it. Or it may be something else -- can you post some samples?

Comment: Or maybe it is [this problem](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43466/15871)?

Comment: Of course it is. The D3200 is a DSLR so the viewfinder is *optical*. It shows 95% of what will be captured but not how it will be rendered in the image, although you would be able to see if focus is achieved or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Perhaps you just need a diopter adjustment?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to photos not being not as sharp as expected try turning off all image processing in the camera's menus. Try to understand all the settings, there are a number of focus settings. You can always reset to factory settings if you get lost and try again. Do post-processing with software, let the camera just take the shot.  Use good third part software, not the freebie Nikon provides with the camera.
My Nikon D7000's factory settings were awful, far too much image processing, slowed down the camera noticeably and produced pics that were not real looking at all.  Your camera should focus fine and you should be able to see it focus through the viewfinder but depending on which focus mode is selected, it may focus on the wrong object.  Try and avoid the dumb settings like face recognition, use AP for low light and a P mode otherwise.
Understanding how aperture, shutter speed and depth of field are related teaches a lot about focus.
Also check the diopter adjustment wheel next to the viewfinder, it's overlooked and if adjusted improperly can cause perfectly focused shots to look fuzzy through the viewfinder but the shots will be in focus unless overridden manually.  Regardless, the viewfinder won't ever give a super clear view of what the lens sees. On a DSLR, the rear screen is good for shot review and menus but poor for taking pics because of the camera's form factor.